# Selenium: click the button element to load then load more reviews

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I am trying to download reviews from this website:
**https://lectricebikes.com/pages/reviews**.
It only shows several reviews, but if you click button "Load More Reviews" it can show more reviews. So I am thinking if i run EC.element_to_be_clickable several times, then i can crawl all reviews by EC.presence_of_all_elements_located, But it only finds the same elements before click the button. Can somebody help me out.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://lectricebikes.com/pages/reviews' 
browser.get(url)
```

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="stamped-reviews-tab"]/ul/li[14]/a'))).click()
    print('button found')
except:
    print('no buttons')

reviews= WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'stamped-review-content-body')))
list1=[]
for r in reviews:
    list1.append(r.text)
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wait time between each click

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
for i in range(1,9999):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="stamped-reviews-tab"]/ul/li[14]/a'))).click()
        print('button found')
        sleep(randint(7,13))
    except:
        print('no buttons')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should proceed another way :

What if you click on the show more button each second in a while loop with 1 sec delay during 2 minutes and then get all the content ?

I looked how it's made and seems to be the best solution to me.

Hope it helps you !

Comment: This is what i thought, in my code, i only apply one click, but even this click, i cannot scrape the new reviews after click.